# MongoDB C# Driver Security

Tags: c#, mongodb, mlab

I am using a Cloud MongoDB (MongoLab) to store my database.  I am using the official MongoDB C# driver to connect to the database.  I am concerned how secure this is as my database contains financial information.

Can someone listen in on this?  And what can they see if they were?

I understand I can apply some application side encryption before and store only encrypted data.  Will this stop someone from duplicating one of my stores?

Comment: Check this link:http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7610/how-to-secure-a-mongodb-instance

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation provided by MongoLab (http://docs.mongolab.com/security/), your MongoDB traffic is not currently encrypted between your application and the database server. They are currently targeting Summer 2014 to enable encryption for all communication. This does not mean your traffic is inherently exposed. I strongly suggest you read the security options available from MongoLab (link provided), including IP whitelisting, firewall rules, and keeping the database inside the same datacenter as your application.

MongoLabs does offer an encrypted option, however it is not supported by the MongoDB C# driver. Their REST API is encrypted using SSL. This may or may not work for you. Check it out here: http://docs.mongolab.com/restapi/

Hope this helps.